# How to use vim help.txt in linux

Tags: linux, vim

When I was trying to use vim help.txt file I found I was unable to open the .txt files included in it. Its instruction at the beginning of the file says:

### Jump to a subject:  Position the cursor on a tag (e.g. |bars|) and hit CTRL-].

But it doesn't work and it shrinks the size of the words on my terminal. I want to know how to open the related files and also how to get my terminal window back to normal.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I tried using g,f at the same time as @ygoncho said, it is trying to find the related file indeed, but it tells me "can't find xxx file in path". Why is that?

Comment: which terminal are you using?

Comment: what is Ubuntu terminal?? I guess you meant gnome-terminal? check the shortcuts setting of the terminal, if there was `ctrl-]` usually it sits "edit->keyboard" or somewhere in preference. also the vim jump works only if your cursor was on a `tag`, not work for all words.

Comment: Move the cursor to file name and press Ctrl + ] , this works very well in all the systems.

But it seems you there could something wrong with tags file that will link the file name with actual file or the files itself could be missing. 

Please check the VIM document path (/usr/share/vim/vim72/doc in my case) for all the necessary that are mentioned in help.txt. Most important tags file . 

If tags file is not there you need to the "ctags" availability on your system .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your kind help! I was using Gnome-terminal. Actually <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> is needed. Just as copy and paste are completed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> in the terminal.

As for the size of the words, it can be adjusted by `view` tab on top selecting `Zoom in` or `Zoom out`. The reason I was stuck was that, I can zoom in by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> but I cannot zoom out by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>, and similarly, it should be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>.
(By `+`  I mean pressing together. `'+'` means the actual key.)

Also worth mentioning, as @Kent pointed out, the settings can be adjusted through `edit` tab.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in some keyboard layouts the `]` key is the same as the `+` or the `-`, but with different modifiers. So when you type `Ctrl-]` your terminal emulator program thinks you are typing `Ctrl-+`, then uses it on its own, to change the size of the font, or something like that.

The solution is to map another key to this function. I'm using `F12` because it is handy and seldom used for anything else. Just add this to your `.vimrc`:

```
nmap <F12> :exe "tjump" expand("<cword>")<CR>
imap <F12> <C-O><F12>
```

Well, technically, the `Ctrl-]` is equivalent to `:tag`, not `:tjump`, but I find that more convenient when using `tags`.